# Definition of a test function

Tags: distribution-theory

I only ever find the expression "test function" used to denote smooth functions with compact support, which is relevant to distributions. But there are also specific kinds of distributions, applicable to a larger range of functions. So I was wondering if the term "test function" wasn't abstract terminology to denote a type of function that can be tested against a distribution of a given type. So in the context of tempered distributions, a test function would mean a Schwartz funcion (ie $x^\alpha \partial^\beta \varphi(x)$ is bounded for all $\alpha, \beta$), whereas for distributions with compact support, a test function would be any smooth function.

This being true would enable to write properties which hold for various sorts of distributions without having to use "respectively" all over the place.

Comment: As far as I am aware, "test function" is only ever used to denote the class of functions belonging to the space $\mathcal{D}=C^{\infty}_{0}$. Yes, it's true that the tempered distributions act on Schwartz functions and distributions with compact support act on smooth functions but I have never heard of them being referred to as "test functions". Perhaps someone else will offer an alternative experience.

Comment: I think you're right. I think it's a shame though, it would save a lot of ink